# How to get the Fortran SUM command result to exceed 2^24 for single precision arrays

Tags: arrays, sum, fortran, fortran95, dot-product

To check memory allocations we populate single precision arrays with unit values and interrogate with the `SUM` and `DOT_PRODUCT` commands. These intrinsics stop counting after 16777216 (= 2^24). How can we get these commands to count billions of elements? We prefer to avoid `DO` loops. This is not a problem with higher precision arrays.

```
program allocator

  use iso_fortran_env
  implicit NONE

  integer, parameter :: sp    = selected_real_kind ( REAL32 )
  integer, parameter :: xlint = selected_int_kind  ( INT64 )

  integer ( xlint )                            :: n = 100000000
  real    ( sp ), allocatable, dimension ( : ) :: array

  integer   ( xlint )     :: alloc_status = 0
  character ( len = 255 ) :: alloc_msg = ""

!   ALLOCATE
    allocate ( array ( 1 : n ), stat = alloc_status, errmsg = alloc_msg )
    if ( alloc_status /= 0 ) print *, 'allocation error on ', n, ' elements: stat = ', alloc_status, ', errmsg = ', alloc_msg

!   POPULATE
    array = 1.0_sp
    write ( *, '( "number of elements allocated = ", g0 )' )    n
    write ( *, '( "sum of elements              = ", g0 )' )    sum ( array )
    write ( *, '( "dot product                  = ", g0, / )' ) dot_product ( array, array )

!   DEALLOCATE
    deallocate ( array, stat = alloc_status, errmsg = alloc_msg )
    if ( alloc_status /= 0 ) print *, 'deallocation error on ', n, ' elements: stat = ', alloc_status, ', errmsg = ', alloc_msg

    write ( *, '( "compiler version = ", A )' ) compiler_version()
    write ( *, '( "compiler options = ", A )' ) trim ( compiler_options() )

end program allocator
```

Output:

```
number of elements allocated = 100000000
sum of elements              = 16777216.
dot product                  = 16777216.

compiler version = GCC version 4.6.2 20111019 (prerelease)
compiler options = -fPIC -mmacosx-version-min=10.6.8 -mtune=core2
```

Comment: You probably know why that number is the result, but why are you against do-loops?  I'm not clear whether you are asking about how to get the larger number or if it's "checking" the allocation that is important.  Could you clarify (and if the latter, add what you want to check)?

Comment: @francescalus Why is that number the result?

Comment: The same way as your n would not fit in an INT32, the sum of array does not fit in REAL32... You could use REAL(SUM(DBLE(array))) if you wanted the result as a single precision number.

Comment: If you compile with `-ffpe-trap=precision` you'll see that you get a runtime error `Program received signal SIGFPE: Floating-point exception - erroneous arithmetic operation.` because you are overflowing a single precision real in your `sum`

Comment: @francescalus Our application is for a diagnostic tool on our Cray farms. The goal is to exploit the natural parallel tools within Fortran to avoid using MPI, OpenMP, etc.

Comment: @Etienne Pellegrini. A clever idea indeed. Thank you.

Comment: @casey. Very nice. Thanks!

Comment: @francescalus We are sweeping through all data types (ints, reals, complex) and all available precisions and grabbing bigger and bigger chunks of memory. We monitor all steps in the allocate-populate-deallocate process and report the sum and dot products to the diagnostic summary. We are collecting timing information and verifying the performance as new machines are brought online.

Comment: You clearly know what tests you want to run, and you have suggestions here on how better to do that.  However, do you need to do sum/dot products or would a simple "test all elements are 1" (etc.) be sufficient?

Comment: As a minor point: when you get to very large `n` you want to specify the integer literal as non-default kind (`100000000000000_xlint`).

Comment: @francescalus My belief is that the declaration in the code and the method you show are equivalent. What separates these methods?  Regarding the sensible idea to test all elements = 1: Trying to drag the FORTRAN 77 crowd into century XXI.

Comment: @dantopa Without the trailing `_xlint` the expression is of default integer kind regardless of the fact it is an initializer for an integer of kind `xlint`.

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong to look at sums, etc., but, philosophically, you are moving from a "is my memory allocation working?" to an "is my numerical analysis correct?" situation.

Comment: @francescalus Thank you for the keen observation on declaration. As for the philosophical point, you have provided an accurate delineation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's due to the limited precision with single precision reals...

Since you only have 24 bits for your significant "digits", your resolution is 1/2**24 = 1/16777216. In other words, you cannot resolve an addition of 1/1677721 to 1, or in your case

```
16777216 + 1 = 16777216
```

To be able to resolve this operations which is required for both `sum` and `dot_product` (even if calculated using simple loops), you would need (at least) another bit of precision:

```
program allocator

  use iso_fortran_env
  implicit NONE

  integer, parameter :: sp    = REAL32
  integer, parameter :: xlint = INT64

  integer ( xlint )                            :: n = 100000000
  real    ( sp ), allocatable, dimension ( : ) :: array
  real    ( REAL64 )                           :: s
  integer ( xlint )                            :: i

  integer   ( xlint )     :: alloc_status = 0
  character ( len = 255 ) :: alloc_msg = ""

!   ALLOCATE
    allocate ( array ( 1 : n ), stat = alloc_status, errmsg = alloc_msg )
    if ( alloc_status /= 0 ) print *, 'allocation error on ', n, ' elements: stat = ', alloc_status, ', errmsg = ', alloc_msg

!   POPULATE
    array = 1.0_sp
    write ( *, '( "number of elements allocated = ", g0 )' )    n
    write ( *, '( "sum of elements              = ", g0 )' )    sum ( array )
    write ( *, '( "dot product                  = ", g0, / )' ) dot_product ( array, array )

    ! Calculate the sum using a double precision float
    s = real( array(1), REAL64 )
    do i=2,n
      s = s + real( array(i), REAL64 )
    enddo ! i
    write ( *, '( "sum of elements              = ", g0 )' )    s
    ! Calculate the dot product using a double precision float
    s = real( array(1), REAL64 )**2
    do i=2,n
      s = s + real( array(i), REAL64 )**2
    enddo ! i
    write ( *, '( "dot product                  = ", g0, / )' ) s

!   DEALLOCATE
    deallocate ( array, stat = alloc_status, errmsg = alloc_msg )
    if ( alloc_status /= 0 ) print *, 'deallocation error on ', n, ' elements: stat = ', alloc_status, ', errmsg = ', alloc_msg

    write ( *, '( "compiler version = ", A )' ) compiler_version()
    write ( *, '( "compiler options = ", A )' ) trim ( compiler_options() )

end program allocator
```

Output:

```
number of elements allocated = 100000000
sum of elements              = 16777216.0
dot product                  = 16777216.0

sum of elements              = 100000000.00000000
dot product                  = 100000000.00000000

compiler version = GCC version 4.8.4 20140605 (prerelease)
compiler options = -cpp -iprefix /home/elias/opt/sde/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.4/ -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -O0 -Wall -Wextra
```

Comment: Indeed, but with "simple loops" a better summation algorithm can be used or, at least, the extra bits of precision don't involve a massive array temporary.

Comment: Right, in other words `1/2**24` is the machine epsilon with single precision. Got it.

Comment: But for me his code worked with ifort 14 and default flags. What magic did the compiler do then?

Comment: @PetrH Possibly intermediate calculations not at single precision; not `(1.+(1.+(1.+(1.+.....)))`; "optimization"; something else.

Comment: @PetrH whatever it is doing, you can't count on the behavior.  The standard stipulates that the result of `sum()` is the same type and kind as the array it is reducing (13.7.161 p4).

Comment: @casey Yes, but one can get pretty close to 1e8 with `real(real32)`.  How close one gets is a quality-of-implementation issue - and as you say isn't defined.

Comment: @francescalus I see, the lesson is that the compiler is free to choose how to perform the intermediate calculations. So it may even depend on things like hardware as well. Or running the sum in parallel could also do it.